# Drive API doc upload from a server without user interaction

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm making application in Django which uploads files from the form and send it to the google drive. So basically I don't know need user's info or have them authenticated on google. From the quickstart guide we use `authorize_url` to get `code` to pass in. However I don't need `oauth` and i just *server-to-server* exchange, give file, and later on take it back with server credentials. All guides and docs that I've read on google provide info with `oauth`. So my question is, is there any chance to not ask user to acccept google `oauth` and make it behind the scences?

Comment: can you clarify to which Drive account your app is uploading? Is it (a) the user's Drive, or (b) a Google account for your application, or (c) a service account?

Comment: @pinoyyid, I am struggling with (c) service account

Comment: service accounts don't use the user's oauth. You need to create a signed JWt and use that to fetch an access token. It's all explained https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount. Most of the Drive examples are for user oauth. You just need to divorce the issues of authentication from the issues of Drive API. Then it will make more sense